# Transfer Mac Mail POP3 Email account to new MAC

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, migration, migration-assistant, pop

I want to move to a new Macbook. However, I have a POP3 email account on Mac Mail with some old emails that I would like to migrate to a new Macbook which are no longer on the mail server. Would Apple Migrate Assistant allow me to move these emails to the new Macbook? Or is there an alternative method that would allow me to achieve this?

Comment: Is use of the Migration Assistant a must, or are you open for other approaches? If the second, please edit your question to indicate so?

Comment: Have edited the question to allow other options to be proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's Migration Assistant will transfer all settings and files from your old Mac to your new one, including all email accounts, regardless of type, IMAP, POP, Exchange, etc.

Comment: Remember to use the Migration Assistant at the very first login of the new Mac, to avoid 'doubled account' issues if you do it later.

Comment: Good point. I usually create an "admin" account. Log in with that, run software update and *then* run Migration assistant. But at first run works well too.

Comment: So is the Migration Assistant literally just copying/moving the hard drive from one mac to another?

Comment: Pretty much. Some stuff is left behind. Caches and the like and things specific to the  source Mac. Not everything, but, everything you need for an identical experience.

Comment: I tried this, two times, in case I missed something. It gives me a choice of transferring "Applications," and there are some applications I do NOT want to transfer. Since at least one menu item (Preferences and Network, or something like that) showed I could go into a submenu, but Applications did not, I didn't want to pick Applications and hit "Next" because I did not want it to start transferring apps I do not want on the new machine. I have yet to see anything that tells me, clearly, how to transfer JUST Mail.

Comment: Applications are 3rd part apps (EG not made by Apple) Mail.app is *included* with macOS. You can't transfer *just* email with migration assistant. There is an option to transfer "user files" (or words to that effect, it's been a while since I used it) **THAT** is what you want to check. Yeah it will bring across all other documents and settings files, but I have yet to see a utility that will transfer *just* email files from one Mac to another. But Migration Assistant will bring over **ALL** your email files and settings, reliably. Every. Single. Time.